# focus on input field using a modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript

How to focus on an input field using Bootstrap ?

```
 $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#inputName').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can focus using ID.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#inputID").focus()},100);
```

Comment: i actually tried that before using $("input:text:visible:first").focus(); still no focus

Comment: I have updated code. try that.. this might work because sometimes controls could not render before code execute.

Comment: same nothing happens

Comment: in which browser ?

Comment: i am testing on chrome

Answer (score 0):

The focus event happens on window load and modal opens without loading the page.
Try making an anchor click event that can trigger the focus on clicking the modal caller.
Example:
      "a class="callModal(by bootstrap)" onclick="myFocusWiz" href="#">call modal

javascript:

```
 function myFocusWiz(){
  $("modalCall...").click(function(){
  $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
  });
  }
```